# Python group by a object key gives errros

Tags: python, json, list, group-by

Does anyone know of a (itertools.groupby if possible too) way in Python to group an array of objects by an object key then create a new array of objects based on the grouping? For example, I have an array of car objects:

```
 cars = [
    {
        'make': 'audi',
        'model': 'r8',
        'year': '2012'
    }, {
        'make': 'audi',
        'model': 'rs5',
        'year': '2013'
    }, {
        'make': 'ford',
        'model': 'mustang',
        'year': '2012'
    }, {
        'make': 'ford',
        'model': 'fusion',
        'year': '2015'
    }, {
        'make': 'kia',
        'model': 'optima',
        'year': '2012'
    },
]
```

I want to make a new array of car objects that's grouped by `make`:

```
 newCarsList = {
        'audi': [
            {
                'model': 'r8',
                'year': '2012'
            }, {
                'model': 'rs5',
                'year': '2013'
            },
        ],

        'ford': [
        {
            'model': 'mustang',
            'year': '2012'
        }, {
            'model': 'fusion',
            'year': '2015'
        }
    ],

    'kia': [
        {
            'model': 'optima',
            'year': '2012'
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried with  but this groupby:

```
def key_func(k): 
    return k['make']

newCarsList = []
for key, value in groupby(cars, key_func): 
  newCarsList.append({key: value})
print(newCarsList)
```

but this returns: `[{'audi': <itertools._grouper object at 0x7f9b2c2bdd30>},  ...]` and can't find how to fix.

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 3):

A simple, mostly-functional solution:

```py
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby
from functools import partial

def del_ret(d, key):
    del d[key]
    return d

dict(map(lambda k_v: (k_v[0], tuple(map(partial(del_ret, key="make"), k_v[1]))),
         groupby(cars, itemgetter("make"))))
```

Change `tuple` to `list` to get identical output to what you want. But I assume you aren't going to modify those, so always use `tuple` in those circumstances…

Answer (score 2):

The `itertools._grouper` is an iterable object. You can extract the values by iterating over it. For example, instead of appending `{key: value}`, you can pull the elements with a list comprehension: `{key: [item for item in value]}`.

It seems that your desired output is a `dict` though, not a `list`. You can get your pattern with

```
result = {}
for key, value in groupby(cars, key_func):
    result[key] = [item for item in value]
    for item in result[key]:
        del item['make']
```

**Edit**: It's nicer to not add items that we're going to delete anyway. That can be done like this:

```
result = {}
for key, value in groupby(cars, key_func):
    result[key] = [{subkey: subval for (subkey, subval)
                    in make.items() if subkey != 'make'}
                   for make in value]
```

Comment: You'd be better off using iterators or otherwise avoiding the double-iteration. EDIT: Yep, your edit has it

Answer (score 0):

```
 df=pd.DataFrame(cars)
 print(df)
 for mytuple in df.itertuples():
     print(mytuple)
```

Comment: what is the result of your groupby statement?  Are tuples good enough